# Static and Media files are not shown in django website - nginx & gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django website on a vps and it's now up and running(after a lot of trouble!), but now my media and static files are not shown in my website and I really tried a lot of ways but none of them worked.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/real_estate/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=shahriar
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate
ExecStart=/home/shahriar/Amlak/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          real_estate.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/var/www/real_estate/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/real_estate/static/assets'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 'static/', BASE_DIR/'static/', '/var/www/real_estate/static/'

]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Media Settings

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR.joinpath('media')
```

And eventually I restarted every service possible but not a single static file was shown.

I tried changing settings.py from this:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 'static/', BASE_DIR/'static/'
]
```

to this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/var/www/real_estate/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/real_estate/static/assets'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 'static/', BASE_DIR/'static/', '/var/www/real_estate/static/'

]
```

I tried changing from this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/real_estate/static/;
    }
    location /assets/ {
        root /var/www/real_estate/assets/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/real_estate/static/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have collected your static files by running the following Django management command: `python manage.py collectstatic`. This command will copy all your static files to the STATIC_ROOT directory you specified in your Django settings.

Comment: Tried that too. didn't work...

Comment: You can follow this tutorial [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04]

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/var/www/real_estate/static/'` this is supposed to be URL, not PATH.  `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` is fine. Go to Nginx and/or Django log, find errors related to static files and add those errors to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www/real_estate/static/;
}
location /media {
    root /home/path/to/real_estate/;
}
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/real_estate/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR/'static/',]
```

Here is what I did about media files: [Media files are not shown: open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/image1.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied) - Django Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77308976/media-files-are-not-shown-open-home-shahriar-amlak-real-estate-media-images)