# Media files are not shown: open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/image1.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied) - Django Nginx

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to see my media files in my website, but I can't. Static files are OK but Media files, despite all my efforts are not visible.

Here is nginx error log:

```
2023/10/17 11:59:33 [error] 48068#48068: *7 open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/ویلا-چمستان-1_uWh54BB.jpg" failed (13: Permi>
2023/10/17 11:59:33 [error] 48068#48068: *6 open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/IMG_20230828_214539_i6yw2Zc.jpg" failed (13:>
2023/10/17 11:59:33 [error] 48068#48068: *5 open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/image1.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), >
2023/10/17 11:59:33 [error] 48068#48068: *4 open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/ویلا-چمستان-1_0kmP7E3.jpg" failed (13: Permi>
2023/10/17 11:59:33 [error] 48068#48068: *3 open() "/home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media/images/455008604_479875.jpg" failed (13: Permission>
```

My nginx configuration file for website:

```
location /static {
        alias /var/www/real_estate/static/;
    }
    location /media {
        root /home/path/to/real_estate(projectname)/;
    }
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/real_estate/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR/'static/',]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


# Media Settings

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

I tried giving permission to my media folder like this:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/real_estate/static
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/shahriar/Amlak/real_estate/media
```

I tried restarting nginx.service and gunicorn.service.

The path to media files is correct, but the website seems to be unable to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

- first I checked nginx error logs: `nano /var/log/nginx/error.log`
- Then I changed my sites nginx configurations:
  `location /media { root /home/path/to/real_estate(projectname)/; }`
- then I gave permission to current user like this, by changing nginx.conf:

> nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

and then I changed the user from www-data to my user name(current user).

- settings.py:

  MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
  MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
- Then I restarted nginx and gunicorn services.

Voila!! It worked...